# Splitting a concatenated string into seperated columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe consiting of one column containing a string seperated by "/" I would like split these seperated strings into new columns denoted by a boolean (if they exist)

```
d = {'col1': ["A/B/C", "B/C", "D/B/A", "C/B"]}
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    col1
0   A/B/C
1   B/C
2   D/B/A
3   C/B
```

the result would be as following:

```
d = {'A': [1, 0, 1, 0], 'B':[1,1,1,1], 'C':[1,1,0,1], 'D':[0,0,1,0]}
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    A   B   C   D
0   1   1   1   0
1   0   1   1   0
2   1   1   0   1
3   0   1   1   0
```

I have attempted with pandas.Series.str.split and pandas.pivot but nothing quite returns the result I am looking for. Any help or nudges in the right direction, would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**`pandas.Series.str.get_dummies`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html)

```
df.col1.str.get_dummies('/')

   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  1  0
1  0  1  1  0
2  1  1  0  1
3  0  1  1  0
```

---

#### Setup

```
d = {'col1': ["A/B/C", "B/C", "D/B/A", "C/B"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```